# Sending POST multipart/form-data request using c++ code

Tags: c++, http-post, multipartform-data

I am trying to write a client, which will connect to a server and make a HTTP POST multipart/form-data request. Please go through following code. With this code, I am not getting any error response.
I am able to get some response, but not exactly what I expet.

With this code I am able to access the URL, but I think server is not reading the parameters (payload).

I am not sure whether I am passing an appropriate payload.

Please help me to write an appropriate payload. Thanks.

```
void BuildHTTPRequest::BuildHeader1(stringstream &hdr,string payload)
{
    hdr << "POST /home/one/user/send_event HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    hdr << "Host:host.domain.com\r\n";
    hdr << "Port:80\r\n";
    hdr << "Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=463762444806\r\n";
    hdr << "Content-Length:" << payload.size() << "\r\n";
    hdr << "\r\n";
    hdr << payload;
}

void BuildHTTPRequest::BuildPayload1(string *payload)
{
    (*payload).append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"interface_version\"\r\n\r\n");
    (*payload).append("01.0.01\r\n");
    (*payload).append("-----------------------------463762444806\r\n");
    (*payload).append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"terminal_id\"\r\n\r\n");
    (*payload).append("1\r\n");
    (*payload).append("-----------------------------463762444806\r\n");
    (*payload).append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"device\"\r\n\r\n");
    (*payload).append("display\r\n");
    (*payload).append("-----------------------------463762444806\r\n");
    (*payload).append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"start_session\"\r\n\r\n");
    (*payload).append("true\r\n");
    (*payload).append("-----------------------------463762444806\r\n");
    (*payload).append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"first_contact\"\r\n\r\n");
    (*payload).append("true\r\n");
    (*payload).append("-----------------------------463762444806--\r\n\r\n");
}
```

Comment: Why do you pass a pointer to the payload string to your BuildPayload1 - function? Does the string contain any data before that?

Comment: No. String doesn't contain any data before that. I am calling these functions as follows: BuildPayload1(&payload1);
 BuildHeader1(ss1,payload1);

Answer (score 0):

You should also have a boundary delimiter before the first payload data and since you aren't putting any preamble before the multipart data, you need 2 CRLF between your request headers and your payload.

> The requirement that the encapsulation boundary begins with a CRLF
>   implies that the body of a multipart entity must itself begin with a
>   CRLF before the first encapsulation line -- that is, if the "preamble"
>   area is not used, the entity headers must be followed by TWO CRLFs.
>   This is indeed how such entities should be composed.

Also, why do use more than 2 hyphens before your boundary value for the delimiter ?

Specs says:

> The Content-Type field for multipart entities requires one parameter,
>   "boundary", which is used to specify the encapsulation boundary. The
>   encapsulation boundary is defined as a line consisting entirely of two
>   hyphen characters ("-", decimal code 45) followed by the boundary
>   parameter value from the Content-Type header field.
>
> ...
>
> Thus, a typical multipart Content-Type header field might look like
>   this:
>
> ```
> Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
> ```
>
> This indicates that the entity consists of several parts, each itself with a structure that is
>   syntactically identical to an RFC 822 message, except that the header
>   area might be completely empty, and that the parts are each preceded
>   by the line
>
> ```
>  --gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
> ```

Try this instead:

```
void BuildHTTPRequest::BuildPayload1(string *payload)
{
    (*payload).append("\r\n--463762444806\r\n");
    (*payload).append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"interface_version\"\r\n\r\n");
    (*payload).append("01.0.01\r\n");
    (*payload).append("--463762444806\r\n");
    (*payload).append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"terminal_id\"\r\n\r\n");
    (*payload).append("1\r\n");
    (*payload).append("--463762444806\r\n");
    (*payload).append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"device\"\r\n\r\n");
    (*payload).append("display\r\n");
    (*payload).append("--463762444806\r\n");
    (*payload).append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"start_session\"\r\n\r\n");
    (*payload).append("true\r\n");
    (*payload).append("--463762444806\r\n");
    (*payload).append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"first_contact\"\r\n\r\n");
    (*payload).append("true\r\n");
    (*payload).append("--463762444806--\r\n\r\n");
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for reply. I tried the code suggested by you. Its sill giving the same output. Is there any other possibility that I can try?

Comment: Are you sure you added all form fields ? Any hidden field on the form ? Other than that, tracing what gets sent and what is the server responding might give you a hint.